# Get Base URL and that with version identifier via Azure APIM Policy

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is it possible to, within policy, get the base url and that with version hightlighted below:
[image]
A url is needed like below:

```
@(base url with version identifier)
```

Above is used in `find-and-replace` element below:

```
  <policies>
        <inbound>
            <base />
            <set-backend-service base-url="https://my.com/oidc" />        
        </inbound>
        <backend>
            <base />
        </backend>
        <outbound>
            <base />
            <find-and-replace from="https://thirdparty/certs" 
                 to="@(base url with version identifier)/certs" />        
        </outbound>
        <on-error>
            <base />
        </on-error>
    </policies>
```

**Update**

How can I get the base url too? The reason is that sometimes, the versioned url is not specified, in this case, only the base url is used to repalce.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#ref-iurl

Comment: Why do you want get base url with policy expression? It will get `Expression syntax is invalid.` while you use expression with your custom string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the base url with version using the below code snippet

```
@{
     var methodRoute = context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace(context.Api.ServiceUrl.ToString(),"");
     var frontEndServiceUrl = context.Request.OriginalUrl.ToString().Replace(methodRoute,"");
}
```

Comment: How can I get the base url too? The reason is that sometimes, the versioned url is not specified, in this case, only the base url is used to repalce.

Comment: @Pingpon I am sorry. I did not understand? The above code will give you the full versioned URL if you are trying with a version. Else it will give you the base url? Is your requirement, to get the base url with and without version? Let me know

Comment: @Pingpong This works fine in my environment. Probably, you can try tracing the request and see how you are getting error 500

Comment: context.Api is null for me. strange

Comment: What level are you applying the policy? And what pricing tier are you in? Is it Consumption tier?

Comment: In Inbound policy. It is Developer (No SLA) tier.

Comment: it works like this: <set-variable name="CachedUrl" value="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.ToString().Replace(".well-known/openid-configuration","certs"))" />

Comment: Is your api published, so you don't get error, but I do?